# CoreData Filter fetch with one-Many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have an Entity with one-many relation attribute

```
    Category: NSManagedObject
      items : [Item]

    Item : NSManagedObject
      name : String
```

I need to fetch and filter Category.items with name that begin with 'A' or 'B' ...
I have tried

```
let f :  NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
f.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"ANY items.name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", term)
```

''''

```
    let f :  NSFetchRequest<MenuCategory> = Category.fetchRequest()
    f.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(items, $c, $c.name BEGINSWITH[c] %@).@count > 0", term)
```

Above resulted in all items to be included.
I have also tried post processing.

```
for xs in fetchResult {
                if let list = xs.items?.allObjects as? [Item] {
                    xs.items = NSSet(array: list.filter { item in
                        return item.name?.starts(with: term) ?? false
                    })
                }
            }
```

I need to return the correct categories that the above solution works however the items list is all of the items not the ones that begin with the input term.
also post fetch processing seems to filter down to 0.

What is the recommended CoreData approach for filtering the set relations.

I am absolutely stumped.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first example should work but remove ANY

Comment: Thanks for the replay if you remove ANY you get 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about a to-one relationship. I guess then the predicate should work as is.

Comment: That is what I thought, but it returns the Categories with all items.  It does not filter the the items .. Ie if there are 3 categories and 2 have items that start with with A; it returns the 2 categories and all of their items not the items that start with A. I was expecting 2 categories and only the items that start with A

Comment: That is not how it works, your predicate will return all categories that has at least one item whose name property start with the given string. You seem to want something completely different, maybe it’s better if you have a fetch request directly on Item

Comment: thanks Joakim, I think you are right and it would work as you suggested; it just would make the futchresultcontroler's sections a bit more complex complex.  I think I have to rethink this a bit..